# itemize and \item option

Tags: lists, itemize

I am using `itemize` and then `\item[option]` inside it. I thought ‘option’ would end up being in boldface, but it doesn't. I'm using LaTeX. Is there a way to easily modify that without having to write `\textbf` for each of the options?
This is what I want to achieve:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{title:}]description
\end{itemize}
```

using this:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[title:]description
\end{itemize}
```

But if I use the second solution, I don't get the same thing as the first one, although I thought an item option would appear in bold without having to type textbf

Comment: Would you please make an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: for future reference, have a look at the `enumitem` package

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a `description` environment instead of `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[foo] text
  \item[bar] text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: What's the difference between itemize and description ? I always used itemize before, and I think it worked, though it's been years so I might be wrong.

Comment: @jlo17 A description environment is to describe things and an itemize environment is to have bullet points or something similar to mark different items.

Comment: @jlo17 See also the chapter in the wikibook about »List Structures« http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumitem` package, it has automatic alignment of item labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[font=\bfseries]
\item[Long label] text
\item[Text] text
\item[Short] text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]